# Traversing from parent to first child element using pseudo class is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, dom, pseudo-element

I know there are many ways to select an element from the DOM tree but I'm trying to traverse to child element 'button#switcher-default' from parent element (i.e., div#container) using pseudo class. It's not working, please let me know what's wrong with it.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#container button:first-child');



   <div id="container">

      <div id="switcher" class="switcher">
        <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
        <button id="switcher-default">
          Default
        </button>
        <button id="switcher-narrow">
          Narrow Column
        </button>
        <button id="switcher-large">
          Large Print
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: can you tell what result you are getting with this?

Comment: @RohitAgrawal with 'document.querySelectorAll('div#container button:first-child')', I am getting output as []

Comment: @RohitAgrawal with 'document.querySelector('div#container button:first-child')', the output is null

Comment: @VXp As I mentioned in my qs, Im trying to do it with pseudo class 'first-child'

Comment: @SamiKh, I have added an answer. I think that's the issue.

Comment: @VXp  I have added an answer. button:nth-of-type will check the elements of only button type. Below line works.

document.querySelectorAll('div#container button:nth-of-type(1)');

Answer (score 1):

By using this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#container button:first-child');
```

> You get all the buttons which are inside `div#container` and are
>   **first-child** of their parent.

The reason you are getting an empty array is because your button is not the first child. You have a `<h3>` tag before that.

Comment: I have added an answer. Below line works even in the presence of <h3> tag ------   document.querySelectorAll('div#container button:nth-of-type(1)');

Answer (score 1):

Below line works. `button:nth-of-type` will check the elements of only button type

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#container button:nth-of-type(1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `querySelector` on `button` like `document.getElementById('container').querySelector('button')` to get the first button inside div with id as `container`.

```js
var child = document.getElementById('container').querySelector('button');
console.log(child);
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="switcher" class="switcher">
    <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
    <button id="switcher-default">
      Default
    </button>
    <button id="switcher-narrow">
      Narrow Column
    </button>
    <button id="switcher-large">
      Large Print
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can also use `querySelectorAll()` but in that case you need to get the first button by `[0]`:

```js
var firstChild = document.getElementById('container').querySelectorAll('button')[0];
console.log(firstChild);
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<div id="container">

  <div id="switcher" class="switcher">
    <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
    <button id="switcher-default">
      Default
    </button>
    <button id="switcher-narrow">
      Narrow Column
    </button>
    <button id="switcher-large">
      Large Print
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my qs, Im trying to do it with pseudo class 'first-child'